# bash command to force file closure on usb drive

Tags: linux, bash, usb-drive

I thought doing a sync in my bash script would force the file to be completely written out.  When I looked at the thumb drive, it showed all the files I had copied, but after a power supply failure, the usb drive showed 0 files.  Do I have to eject the drive manually or is there something I can do programmatically in my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to eject the usb device from your bash script a simple `umount` on the device should do the trick. For example

```
mount /dev/usb /mnt/usb
# Your copy operations here... then on success:
umount /mnt/usb
```

Comment: That's certainly a possibility.  Right now it does an automount in Fedora 16 but I'm considering turning this off.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to use the linux sync instruction that syncronize writing over disk if you're usb key is using a journalized file system